# How to make Twig template include file in same bundle?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm relatively new to Symfony.  I have a bundle with twig templates that are automatically loaded with annotations in a directory structure like:

```
src/bundle/Resources/views/Default/
```

One of my templates has a big chunk of code repeated a bunch of times (with a few minor changes each instance) that I think doing an [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) a few times formatted like this:

```
{% include 'form_include.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

with different variables for each instance should work well.  But the debugger is telling me that it's looking for the include file in

```
/app/Resources/
```

But the template is really specific to this bundle and I wouldn't want it kept elsewhere.  I tried using the `../../src....` method to specify its location with no luck.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can provide a path using the bundle's name:

```
{% include 'YourBundleNameBundle:Default:form_include.html.twig' with {
    'foo': bar
} %}
```

Where each part is separated by `:` and:

- `YourBundleNameBundle` corresponds to `src/YourBundleNameBundle/Resources/views/`
- `Default` corresponds to the `/Default` directory in this folder
- `form_include.html.twig` corresponds to `form_include.html.twig` in this folder

So, the `'YourBundleNameBundle:Default:form_include.html.twig'` value will load the `src/bundle/Resources/views/Default/form_include.html.twig` file.

This syntax works for the different Twig functions: `include`, `extends`, etc.

It is useful for allowing [templates inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates).

Comment: Awesome.  This works.  I may end up using ABM_Dan's suggestion though as that seems more appropriate for my needs, but your answered the question asked so I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I'm happy to see I helped you. :) This syntax work for loading macro too, see the `import` function in ABM_Dan's link.

Comment: (I mean, if you want to put the macro in another file; it's also possible to define and use a macro in the same file)

Comment: @DanGoodspeed After further reflection, I think the macro is more appropriate. Including the same file may take more time than using a macro. Feel free to accept the other answer if it better fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a macro instead?

From: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

> Macros are comparable with functions in regular programming languages. They are useful to put often used HTML idioms into reusable elements to not repeat yourself.
>
> Here is a small example of a macro that renders a form element:
>
> ```
> {% macro input(name, value, type, size) %}
>   <input type="{{ type|default('text') }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value|e }}" size="{{ size|default(20) }}" />
> {% endmacro %}
> ```
>
> Macros differs from native PHP functions in a few ways:
>
> Default argument values are defined by using the default filter in the macro body;
>   Arguments of a macro are always optional.
>   If extra positional arguments are passed to a macro, they end up in the special varargs variable as a list of values.
>   But as with PHP functions, macros don't have access to the current template variables.
>
> You can pass the whole context as an argument by using the special _context variable.
>
> Macros can be defined in any template, and need to be "imported" before being used (see the documentation for the import tag for more information):
>
> ```
> {% import "forms.html" as forms %}
> ```
>
> The above import call imports the "forms.html" file (which can contain only macros, or a template and some macros), and import the functions as items of the forms variable.
>
> The macro can then be called at will:
>
> ```
> <p>{{ forms.input('username') }}</p>
> <p>{{ forms.input('password', null, 'password') }}</p>
> ```
>
> If macros are defined and used in the same template, you can use the special _self variable to import them:
>
> ```
> {% import _self as forms %}
>
> <p>{{ forms.input('username') }}</p>
> ```
>
> When you define a macro in the template where you are going to use it, you might be tempted to call the macro directly via _self.input() instead of importing it; even if seems to work, this is just a side-effect of the current implementation and it won't work anymore in Twig 2.x.
>
> When you want to use a macro in another macro from the same file, you need to import it locally:
>
> ```
> {% macro input(name, value, type, size) %}
>   <input type="{{ type|default('text') }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value|e }}" size="{{ size|default(20) }}" />
> {% endmacro %}
>
> {% macro wrapped_input(name, value, type, size) %}
>   {% import _self as forms %}
>
>   <div class="field">
>      {{ forms.input(name, value, type, size) }}
>   </div>
> {% endmacro %}
> ```

Comment: Can you please add an example (how a macro is defined and used) in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: It would be hard for me to provide an example more appropriate than the official dev's one. so you might want to check here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

Comment: It is recommended to always add code in answers, see this meta discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/237701 You can add the example from the documentation. So this answer will be useful even if the link doesn't work.

Comment: I know, but the code won't fit in the comment. I might edit the main answer later.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to improve your answer, but you didn't need to paste all the page, one example was enough. :)